# using angular-ui bootstrap typeahead how do i fetch values from json to feed in to two different input tags

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have done an autocomplete from a json file in an input tag, the json file has multiple attributes, i want a separate input carry a different attribute from the json file, eg: one one input should fetch the "driver_name" and other should fetch the "vehicle_number", the second input tag needs to be filled automatically, once we select the data from the first input tag

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"driver_name": "Rohit",
"driver_phone": "9176649143",
"vehicle_type": "indica",
"vehicle_number": "TN 06 AR 4556"
},
{
"id": 2,
"driver_name": "john",
"driver_phone": "9176648143",
"vehicle_type": "fiat",
"vehicle_number": "CA 06 AR 4556"
}
]
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <div class="input-group m-bot15">
      <input ng-model="tripsheet.vehicle_no" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Vehicle No" typeahead="Unidade.vehicle_number as Unidade.vehicle_number for Unidade in getUnidades($viewValue)"> 
    </div>

    <div class="input-group m-bot15">
      <input ng-model="tripsheet.driver_name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Vehicle No" typeahead="Unidade.driver_name as Unidade.driver_name for Unidade in getUnidades($viewValue)"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {

 $scope.Selected = undefined;
 $scope.getUnidades = function($viewValue) {
    return $http.get(urldr + '/all').then(function(response){
      return response.data;
    });
 };
}
```

Comment: Pass in a 2nd argument as the filter key, loop your data on return and only return values within the filter

Comment: i tried but it does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just add a filter to the typeahead function:

```
$scope.getUnidades = function($viewValue, filter) {
    return $http.get(urldr + '/all').then(function(response){
        var values = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i][filter].indexOf($viewValue) > -1) 
                values.push(response.data[i])
        }
        return values;
    });
};
```

And `filter` is the property name to filter on